# Is there such a number that is equal to the product of almost all of the primes that precede it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Propose a positive integer $n$.

Let $p_{n}$ be the largest prime that is <$n$.

Let $p_{p_{n}}$ be the largest prime number <$p_{n}$

Could you have such a value of $n$ where $n = 2*3*5*7*11*...*$$p_{p_{n}}$ ?

I ask because this would imply that $p_{n}$ = $n-1$

If there is such a value, could it also be possible to have an infinite number of possible values of $n$ that give this result?

Comment: For the notation, I thought $p_{n-1}$ would be the largest prime number $< n-1$.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't think of any other notation to use. I'm happy to edit if you know any better notations though.

Comment: $p _ { p _ n }$?

Comment: The two notations contradict each other, but it's not a real problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the product of all the primes less than $n$ except for the largest one - this is the product you've defined.  Then you have

$$f(4) = f(5) = 2$$

$$f(6) = f(7)  = 2 \times 3 = 6$$

$$f(8) = f(9) = f(10) = f(11) = 2 \times 3 \times 5 = 30$$

$$f(12) = f(13) = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 210$$

$$f(14) = f(15) = f(16) = f(17) = 2\times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 = 2310$$

and so on.  So you can see that $n = 6$ works.  You can also see that the product of primes grows so quickly that there won't be any others

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. A bit unfortunate that it didn't work out as I'd hoped but thank you for your help.